# Update row in database using LINQ - object copied

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

```
var queryResult = this.kindergardenDataContext.Groups.Where(g => g.group_id == groupToAdd.group_id && g.group_enabled==true);
                if (queryResult != null && queryResult.Count() != 0)
                {

                    Group groupToEdit = queryResult.First();

                    groupToEdit.group_name = groupToAdd.group_name;
                    groupToEdit.group_create_date = groupToAdd.group_create_date;
                    groupToEdit.Kindergarden = groupToAdd.Kindergarden;
                    groupToEdit.GroupGuardian = groupToAdd.GroupGuardian;
                    groupToEdit.Room = groupToAdd.Room;     

                }
                this.kindergardenDataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Hi. Im beginner in LINQ. Here is ok, but foreigns key kindergarden, groupguardian, room has been duplicated in database (added new rows in database in kindergarden, groupguardian, room table). How can I set good reference to update row in group table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you retrieved `groupToAdd.Kindergarden`, groupToAdd.GroupGuardian`, and`groupToAdd.Room`from`this.kindergardenDataContext` or attached them with the right IDs set, that is the expected behviour.  It doesn't know that you mean the same object instances that already resides in the database.